# C++ Ncurses , how to check what the current mouse position is

Tags: c++, ncurses

How Do I  Check What The Mouse Position is when I move the mouse in Ncurses. I have tried searching but couldnt find any answer . I have seen the use of `getmouse()` , but getting the mouse co-ordinates from that function requires enabling an event first. I want to get the position of the mouse without clicking the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You get the cursor position by calling GetCursorPos.

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
```

This returns the cursor position relative to screen coordinates. Call ScreenToClient to map to window coordinates.

```
if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x and p.y are now relative to hwnd's client area
}
```

Comment: I said "mouse position" not cursor position , they are two different things , also I this isnt even ncurses ???

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. I completely misunderstood your question

Comment: oh ok , no worries